# "You are next" vs "It is your turn". Do they have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

> You are next.
>   It is your turn.

These sentences seem to have the same meaning. Is there any difference?

Comment: I would expect _You are next_ to mean _after Bob who is taking his turn right now_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not have the same meaning since they speak about different tenses, you use " it is your turn" with someones to suggest that the turn that has **just started/in action** is his/hers, conversly you use "you are next" to indicate that the **upcoming turn** is going to be his/hers.